# Customize UINavigationController Push/pop animation with performance issues

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, core-animation

I want to customize the push and pop animation with Core Animation!  For example, I write some code in the pushViewController like this:

```
{
    //save currrent view's snapshot`

    m_curLayer = [self _ConstructLayerByView:self.view];

    [super pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];

    //save the next view's snapshot
    m_nextLayer = [self _ConstructLayerByView:self.view];

    //add these two new layers to self.view.layer, and add customized animations to them.
    [self _PushAnimation]; 
}
```

The animation works as my expectation, but performance is bad. after some profiling, I found the renderInContext is very slow. my snapshot function is:

```
+ (id)CaptureView:(UIView *)view
{

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.frame.size, YES, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    CGContextRef contenxt =  UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    [view.layer renderInContext:contenxt];

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return (id) [newImage CGImage];
}
```

so I want to ask if there is a way to optimize the renderInContext, or a better way to customize the animation?

Answer (score 1):

Code your own navigation controller using the new 'container' functionality added to UIViewController, or subclass UINavigationController and override all the push and pop methods. Probably the latter will work fine - I subclasses it for other reasons and my subclass works just fine.

Many have commented that with the new in ios5 container methods, it's now possible to recreate most if not all of the existing container classes.

Comment: In fact, I subclass UINavigationController and override the push/pop methods. but I just met some performance issues.